# Return a one message into loop jquery

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop, conditional-statements

Well , I created a simple searcher but I need return a one message   when the word not exists, but the first word work fine, but when I write the last word the loop break instantly , how to tour all words and send a one alert without break the loop?

Thanks in advance

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>buscador</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

/*iniciando el buscador*/
$("#buscar").click(function(){
    var dato =$("#palabra").val().toLowerCase();
    var myArray = [ "hello", "world","apple","bread","milk","pencil"];

        for ( var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i = i + 1 ){
            var flag = false;
                if(dato==myArray[i])
                {
                    alert("exist");
                    return false;
                }

                else if(dato!=myArray[i]){
                 flag=true;
                }
                if(flag) {alert("no exist"); return false;}

            }/*end foreach*/


});
});

</script>

<body>

<form method="post" action="" id="form-search">
<input type="text" id="palabra" name="palabra" placeholder="buscar"/>
<button id="buscar" name="buscar">Buscar</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest, I'd suggest:

```
$('#buscar').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var needle = $('#palabra').val().toLowerCase(),
        haystack = ['hello','world','apple','milk','bread','pencil'],
        found = haystack.indexOf(needle) == -1 ? 'Not found' : 'Found';
    console.log(found);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SZcyY/).

Or, if your browser doesn't support `Array.indexOf()`, you could use the `for` loop as above:

```
$('#buscar').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var needle = $('#palabra').val().toLowerCase(),
        haystack = ['hello','world','apple','milk','bread','pencil'],
        found = false;
    for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i < len; i++){
        if (haystack[i] === needle){
            found = true;
        }
    }
    console.log(found ? 'Found' : 'Not found');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SZcyY/1/).

Comment: works correctly, was what I needed, thank you very much, but how to develop it could be done or if it really was wasting time?

Answer (score 0):

try using $.inArray(value, array)

It returns -1 if value is not their in array